# Samba Share to Require Password Debugging

Tags: centos, samba, authentication

I've recently set up Samba on one of my CentOS 7 servers and it works fine, it allows anyone to access it as long as they are on the LAN.

Now I need to set up a second share that can only be accessed with a password.

I added a linux user for samba with a password

I then edited my smb.conf

```
unix charset = UTF-8
dos charset = CP392
workgroup = WORKGROUP

hosts allow = 192.168.20.0/24 127.0.0.1

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
map to guest = Bad User

[Public]
    path = /share/public
    writable = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777

[Secret]
    path = /share/secret
    browsable = yes
    valid users = samba
    force user = samba
    create mask = 777
    directory mask = 777
```

Then I installed samba-client and create the samba user password

```
smbpasswd -a samba
```

When I try to mount the share on windows it brings up the request for user and password but when I enter the samba username and password it denies me access.

Did I miss something in the setup?

Comment: There are potentially important parts of the `smb.conf` missing. Could you perhaps give the full one minus comments (redacted as needed): `grep -vE '^[#;]' /etc/samba/smb.conf|grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'`

Comment: ... also, did you check the folder permissions? And what `passdb backend` are you using etc? Problem is that it's not even clear whether the user that samba would try to log in is the one from Samba's own passdb or a system account.

Comment: It would be ideal to have the user logging in using the samba system account, I will add other smb.conf settings to my question

Comment: I know this should be kinda implied by the CentOS version, but which Samba are you using?

Comment: it's version 4.1.12